# windows application open console and write in it

Tags: c#

How can i open console in C# graphical windows application and then write some data in console. Can i even open a console from win app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check into  Win32.[AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944(VS.85).aspx)()

Comment: Thx. This is solution:

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 AllocConsole();

Comment: http://vbcity.com/blogs/jatkinson/archive/2010/02/17/windows-interop-inside-kernel32-part-1-allocconsole-amp-createhardlink.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Say you have a winform application in visual studio.  Go to the Project Properties > Application Tab > Change "Output Type:" to Console Application.

Now when you launch your winform a console application will fire in the background.  You can write to this console application with standard out.  E.G.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Instructions [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.csharp-station.com%2Ftutorials%2Flesson01.aspx&ei=2I4fTOz3L4KC8gbqsqGrDA&usg=AFQjCNFdzrGMMiXrJVU40XZIzfDNbUAfCA&sig2=krhtVdLbPO59WYLP8VtvcQ).

1st result for Google: `c# write console`.

Incredibly, this is the least documented and most useful thing to do in C#.

Comment: i have graphical win application. i can not use console like that!

Comment: When posting a link, I suggest giving a quick summary, or pasting a relevant code snippet which addresses the question-at-hand, so that someone should be able to use information from stackoverflow to determine appropriateness of the answer before digging through your link.

For example, you could have done: Instructions -here- describe how to use the Console.WriteLine and Console.ReadLine functions from C#.

This way, OP will be able to comment on the answer without looking at the link, and also this provides some information if the link were to disappear one day.